# ejabberd mod_multicast won't allow relaying

Tags: ejabberd

I am using the latest (commit 9574e71e8db595ce7b2fa2f8fbfc38deec2ad74b) version of ejabberd and tries to make the mod_multicast module work, but I'm failing.

I have this:

```
modules:
    mod_multicast:
        host: "multicast.cego.dk"
        allow: all
```

which I believe should work, however I get this response when sending a massage:

```
<message from="multicast.cego.dk"
         to="robert78@komogvind.dk/13809541201432712492488165"
         type="error">
<addresses xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/address">
<address type="to"
         jid="betatester01@komogvind.dk"/>
<address type="to"
         jid="robert78@komogvind.dk"/>
<body>
Hello, World!
</body>
</addresses>
<error code="403"
       type="auth">
<forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
<text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">
Packet relay is denied by service policy
</text>
</error>
</message>
```

Why is this?
I also tried with 'allow: admin' and 'allow: multicast' and then defining a multicast acl as described in the documentation but all attempts fail.
The "multicast.cego.dk" service shows up in service discovery and I can query it with service discovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, ejabberd only support multicasting to local user and does not support relaying.

I created a feature request for you on ejabberd ticket tracker:
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/583

Comment: Excellent, but it is in fact a local user...both domains are hosted on the same server. Ain't that local enough?

Comment: In your example, you have: multicast.cego.dk with users that send packet and referenced in address field being on domain komogvind.dk. This is two different domains. You should use the multicast service of the user domain. Do not forget that virtual host in ejabberd is intended to be transparent and  to work the same if hosted on same instance or on two different instances.

Comment: Alright then. I thought that all users on domains handled by the same server were considered local. Thanks for clarifying.